# Mediaplayer error once used multiple times

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've created a game which is nearly complete, but I've still got one problem:
Once I press a button I want a sound to play, I did this with this code:

```
                    MediaPlayer planeSound = MediaPlayer.create(ObjectCanvas.getDrawContext(), R.raw.plane);
                planeSound.start();
```

It works perfectly, but the only problem is when I press it a lot of times, then the MediaPlayer gives a error which is error (-19,0). I searched but I can't find a solution for this. If the error happens the MediaPlayer won't play any sounds anymore untill the actvity is recreated. The game doesn't get a FC, but just the error (-19,0).

I don't know how to fix it, I hope someone can give me some suggestions or explanation.

Comment: Better go for `SoundPool`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for sound pool, or reuse one instance of media player, or release each instance once you have finished with it.

> When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the
>   resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result
>   in an exception.

etc

> It is also recommended that once a MediaPlayer object is no longer
>   being used, call release() immediately so that resources used by the
>   internal player engine associated with the MediaPlayer object can be
>   released immediately. Resource may include singleton resources such as
>   hardware acceleration components and failure to call release() may
>   cause subsequent instances of MediaPlayer objects to fallback to
>   software implementations or fail altogether. Once the MediaPlayer
>   object is in the End state, it can no longer be used and there is no
>   way to bring it back to any other state.

See the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html