# Media player not working properly

Tags: java, android

I am making and app in which you press buttons to play sounds.It seems to work at first but after the 5-6 press it stops playing sounds. Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


private ImageButton pad1, pad2, pad3, pad4, pad5, pad6, pad7, pad8, pad9, pad10, pad11, pad12;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pad1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad1);
    pad2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad2);
    pad3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad3);
    pad4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad4);
    pad5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad5);
    pad6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad6);
    pad7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad7);
    pad8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad8);
    pad9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad9);
    pad10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad10);
    pad11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad11);
    pad12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad12);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}



    public void onPad1Click(View view) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p1);
        mp.start();
    }

public void onPad2Click(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p2);
    mp.start();
}

public void onPad3Click(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p3);
    mp.start();

}

public void onPad4Click(View view) {

    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p4);
    mp.start();
}

public void onPad5Click(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p5);
    mp.start();
}

public void onPad6Click(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p6);
    mp.start();
}

public void onPad7Click(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p7);
    mp.start();
}

public void onPad8Click(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p8);
    mp.start();
}

public void onPad9Click(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p9);
    mp.start();
}

public void onPad10Click(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p10);
    mp.start();
}

 public void onPad11Click(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p11);
     mp.start();
}

 public void onPad12Click(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p12);
   mp.start();
}
}
```

I dont know what it could be the sounds are very short so i dont think that is the problem. I hope someone can help solve this. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mediaplayer error once used multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509969/mediaplayer-error-once-used-multiple-times)

Comment: i added mp.release(); after the mp.start(); but now it doesnt even play the sound. any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use SoundPool instead of MediaPlayer for short playback.

Add following variables:

```
SoundPool soundPool = null;
int sound1_id;
int sound2_id;
```

Add to your onCreate()-Method (instead of MediaPlayer):

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
sound1_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p1, 1);
sound2_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p2, 1);
```

and at the specific onClick():

```
soundPool.play(sound1_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
```

Comment: Good luck. It is also better in performance than MediaPlayer.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked. I have one other issue which is not connected to this if by some way you know how to fix it will be awesome. So i need to make the buttons resize for different screen sizes and i put android:weight in every button and that works for the width but not for the hight. if you somehow know ill be very thankful. :)